# Unable to load DLL 'libcurl.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, libcurl

I am using LibCurlNet on my asp.net project. I post some fields to server with it. I downloaded library and added it to my project as reference. At first I could run my project.
But now when I run project, I have an exception:

> {System.DllNotFoundException: Unable
>   to load DLL 'libcurl.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>   at
>   SeasideResearch.LibCurlNet.External.curl_global_init(Int32
>   flags)    at
>   SeasideResearch.LibCurlNet.Curl.GlobalInit(Int32
>   flags) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\WebSites\WebProjectUpload\App_Code\Curl.cs:line
>   47    at Post.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\WebSites\WebProjectUpload\App_Code\Post.cs:line
>   21}

and I have the exception at line "Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);"

When I try to add reference to my project, in bin folder I found three .dll file but I just add the "LibCurlNet.dll". Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the DLL in the build output folder?

Comment: I can't see the output folder.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try placing the dll in your bin folder and adding the reference from there?
Alternatively you can place your assembly in the GAC.

Comment: @Dante: hey i'm also running into same error, but i have tried adding my dll's in bin folder and referenced it, then also im geting the same error, will you please let me know where would be things gone wrong ??